# How can I modify the x-labels on a barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I succeded I plotting the following barplot
I would like to

- add all tick-marks on the x-axis
- plot only say 10 labels on the x axis.

How can I do this ?

```
> m = matrix(abs(rnorm(40)),20,2)
> set.seed(1)
> m = matrix(abs(rnorm(40)),20,2)
> rownames(m) = seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2011-01-20'),by=1)
> barplot(t(m),beside=T,col=c('red','blue'),las=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show the code that you used to create this graph? For ticks on the x-axis you may need to use (x,y) points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516733/display-ticks-for-every-second-observation-rotated-labels ?

Comment: I edited my post with code

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the x-axis labels are character expressions as opposed to dates. Make sure you conform them into a date format in order for R to understand that this is a continuous scale.